# electron open new window from renderer process or main process

Tags: javascript, electron, ipc

I am working on an electron app.

I have a renderer process, and wish to open a new window to read some input, then pass input info back to the renderer process.

In most tutorials, people use ipcRenderer / ipcMain to open an new window from main process.

Can I just open a new window from current renderer process (instead of using ipc to communicate with main), and then take the input? What's the potential risk if doing so?